# Program terminated abnormally

Tags: c++, crash, g++, g++4.9

I'm writing a bot for codeingame.com in C++. I'm compiling my program fine on my PC. Then I'm sending it to the codeingame.com server for execution. So I have no way to debug it locally.

I've written a predicate for sorting a piece of data. Here is the relevant piece of code:

**Code 1**

```
for (const auto &zz : zone_to_zone)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> can_go;

    for (int to : zz.second)
        can_go.push_back({ to, visit_count[to] });

    sort(can_go.begin(), can_go.end(),
        [](const pair<int, int>& z1, const pair<int, int>& z2)
    {
        return z1.second < z2.second;
    });
```

This program crashes on the server after number of execution of the sorting above and gives the following error:

```
Standard Error Stream:

Aborted.

at raise.c. function __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) on line 56
at abort.c. function __GI_abort () on line 89
at libc_fatal.c. function __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff6b1bc60 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") on line 175
at malloc.c. function malloc_printerr (action=1, str=0x7ffff6b17d1e "free(): invalid pointer", ptr=<optimized out>) on line 4996
at malloc.c. function _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) on line 3840
at new_allocator.h. function __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Zone>::deallocate ( this=0x7fffffffe8e0, __p=0x61e0f0) on line 110
at alloc_traits.h. function std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Zone> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x61e0f0, __n=32) on line 383
at stl_vector.h. function std::_Vector_base<Zone, std::allocator<Zone> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffe8e0, __p=0x61e0f0, __n=32) on line 178
at stl_vector.h. function std::_Vector_base<Zone, std::allocator<Zone> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffe8e0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) on line 160
at stl_vector.h. function std::vector<Zone, std::allocator<Zone> >::~vector ( this=0x7fffffffe8e0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) on line 425
```

If I change the predicate slightly:

**Code 2**

```
for (const auto &zz : zone_to_zone)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> can_go;

    for (int to : zz.second)
        can_go.push_back({ to, visit_count[to] });

    sort(can_go.begin(), can_go.end(),
        [](const pair<int, int>& z1, const pair<int, int>& z2)
    {
        return false;
    });
```

Then the program doesn't crash!

The server is using g++4.9. Why is this happening? What's wrong in Code 1?

Comment: The problem is likely to be somewhere outside of the shown code. There is a corrupt memory, but the code posted can not corrupt memory.

Comment: Note: if you can view output from stderr, you can "debug" remotely with messages.  If you think the exception is generated in the sort routine, you could put a try/catch block around it, and output useful debug information to stderr that will help identify what the can_go vector looks like (size, values, perhaps print out the entire thing depending on size, etc).  Good luck.  Since I'm seeing malloc errors, and the exception isn't thrown when you return false, I'm betting the problem is in the swap portion of the sort when true is returned.

Comment: [mcve] please. We need to know the type of `zone_to_zone`, and what `visit_count` is and how it's populated

Comment: @SergeyA, @AndyG: I've used `vector`s and `unordered_map` all over the code. I cannot come up with a minimal, complete and verifiable code to this problem. Moreover, I don't have all data that the server has to run. The surprising thing is if I remove the sort call, there is never a corrupt memory.